# Project server WorkFlow, permission issues

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, project-server

I am developing a workflow using Project Server 2013 and sharepoint designer.

Everything works fine until I try to set the value of a project field. When I do I get a 401 error (before I'd got a 403 error but solved it granting elevated permissions).

I've tried everything (or I think I did):

- configuring the stages (requiring check-in)
- configuring the custom fields (field not controlled by workflow)
- configuring the site collection features (grant workflows app permissions)

But nothing seems to work, I always get:

```
System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401 {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["26"],"SPRequestGuid":["94133bac-d37e-4a3d-84c6-ed9c1db025b8"],"request-id":["94133bac-d37e-4a3d-84c6-ed9c1db025b8"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the admin account running the workflow did not have permissions to access some user groups.

By granting that all user could access to see the members of every group both problems were solved and elevated permissions weren't necessary anymore.

Hope this helps anyone.